# is it substitute by or substitute for by

Tags: prepositions

Original sentence:

> You substitute A for B.

Which of these is correct transformation of that sentence?

> B is substituted by A.

> B is substituted for by A.

Comment: Those are not passive transforms of the example sentence you started with. _You_ was the agent subject, not _A_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Replace with" versus "replace by"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151309/replace-with-versus-replace-by) (**active/passive** has a bearing on preferred preposition usage).

Comment: @WeatherVane I would love to do that. How can I edit and improve it? It was simply closed with little explanation, so I don't know how to better articulate it.

Comment: If you edit it, it will be flagged as "recent activity" and people can vote to reopen. Reposting the almost identical question isn't the way forward, as you should know.

Comment: Edit your question so it fits our guidelines and then post on English.Meta to see if you can get people to vote to re-open it.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox I don't know how better to ask this. It's a very simple question, and should require only a very simple answer. Could you point me to which guideline it violates?

Comment: It says in the close banner: "Please include the research you've done"

Comment: @KitZ.Fox should that research be peer-reviewed?

Comment: @KitZ.Fox I would happy to do further research on this topic, but because I don't know enough to articulate the question to a search engine, I'm struggling to find an answer. That is the entire reason that sites like this exist.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox My original question *did* in fact contain the information I researched that helped me to articulate my question, but it was closed because it wasn't correct.

Comment: You are mistaken. This site is not for inarticulate questions. If your original question was clearer than this one, than you might consider editing it again.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox You are mistaken; I never claimed the site was for inarticulate questions. I said it was for questions that are difficult to articulate to a search engine, which is another thing entirely. Why should I edit back to the original question? It was already closed in that state and I have no knowledge to improve upon it. I don't have the knowledge to follow up on my research to better understand what questions to ask. I have no recourse whatsoever because of the absolute refusal to be helpful in any way here.

Comment: @vaer-k "Gatekeeping experts use their pedantic powers to prevent learners from asking questions, so I have stripped as much as possible from this question in order to eliminate as many possible opportunities for pedants to object to some trivial misconception in my question" This isn't the reason most likely to be successful. Also it's probably a duplicate. Also, you can probably use google ngrams and compare the relative frequencies. But on the surface it is not an unreasonable question. If it stays closed here maybe try [ell.se]?

Comment: @Mitch thank you, that's a good idea. it's refreshing to find at least one person willing to offer some helpful advice.

Comment: @vaer-k What the others said ain't wrong. Even if they are ... unwelcoming... it is still their house. You catch more flies with honey than pissing in a violin and all those mixed and jumbled metaphors.

Comment: Most of the previous questions about **double prepositions** (such as the OP's *for by*) are on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), but here is a closed [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/359311/are-two-prepositions-allowed-along-with-one-another-in-the-english-language) question on the topic.

Comment: @WeatherVane "Double prepositions". Thank you! Now I have something to go on. That's all I had hoped for

Comment: @vaer-k Just so you understand the mechanics of this site, this question was originally closed by 3 people, not just the single one you called out. But the process worked (your posting on meta, the action taken by the mod) and you have a link to the duplicates now.

Comment: @Mitch I understand and I appreciate your follow-up explanation, and I appreciate the links to the duplicates too