# Is it substitute by or substitute for by

Tags: prepositions

Original sentence:

> You substitute A for B.

Which of these is correct transformation of that sentence?

> B is substituted by A.

> B is substituted for by A.

Comment: Please edit and improve the [previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/601023/how-do-you-place-the-prepositions-for-substitute-in-the-passive), instead of just reposting it.